# Average of column values based on intervals of a second column

Tags: python, numpy, average, multiple-columns

I have a dataset that has two columns, column 1 is the time which goes from 1 to 9 seconds and column 2 is the probability of an event in a specific second with values of 30, 69, 56, 70, 90, 59, 87, 10, 20.

I am trying to get the average probability in a time interval (after 2 seconds for this case), like the probability between 2 to 3 seconds, 2 to 4 seconds, 2 to 5 seconds,....2 to 9 seconds.

I tried the following approach where I defined a function `t_inc` which has increments of 1 greater than 2. However, I am getting the following error msg (`P_slice_avg_1` in the code):

> Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (9,) (7,)

because my t_inc has a shape of 7.

When I tried to do it in a manual way (`P_slice_avg_2` in the code) it works but not feasible if I want to do it for a huge number of intervals.

Any help in how to generalize it would be greatly helpful.

```py
import numpy as np
data=np.loadtxt('C:/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/Sample.txt')

t=data[:,0] # t goes from 1 to 9
P=data[:,1] # probability of an event in a specific second

i= np.arange(1, 8 , 1)
t_inc= 2 + i 

P_slice_avg_1= np.mean(P[(t>=2) & (t<=t_inc)]) # I thought this would give me the averages between 2 and values of t_inc

P_slice_avg_2= np.mean(P[(t>=2) & (t<=3)]), np.mean(P[(t>=2) & (t<=4)]), np.mean(P[(t>=2) & (t<=5)]), np.mean(P[(t>=2) & (t<=6)]), np.mean(P[(t>=2) & (t<=7)]), np.mean(P[(t>=2) & (t<=8)]), np.mean(P[(t>=2) & (t<=9)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a vectorized approach exploiting [numpy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```py
import numpy as np
t = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) 
P = np.array([30, 69, 56, 70, 90, 59, 87, 10, 20], dtype=float) 
i = np.arange(1, 8 , 1)
t_inc= 2 + i 

T = np.tile(t[:,None], len(i))
P = np.tile(P[:,None], len(i))
```

[np.tile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) constructs an array by repeating it the number of given times, in this case we will have `len(i)` copies of `t` and of `P`, namely:

```
P
array([[30., 30., 30., 30., 30., 30., 30.],
       [69., 69., 69., 69., 69., 69., 69.],
       [56., 56., 56., 56., 56., 56., 56.],
       [70., 70., 70., 70., 70., 70., 70.],
       [90., 90., 90., 90., 90., 90., 90.],
       [59., 59., 59., 59., 59., 59., 59.],
       [87., 87., 87., 87., 87., 87., 87.],
       [10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10.],
       [20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20., 20.]])
```

Now we set to zero all the elements not satisfying the required condition using [np.logical_or](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html):

```
P[np.logical_or(2>T, T>t_inc)]=0
P
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [69., 69., 69., 69., 69., 69., 69.],
       [56., 56., 56., 56., 56., 56., 56.],
       [ 0., 70., 70., 70., 70., 70., 70.],
       [ 0.,  0., 90., 90., 90., 90., 90.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., 59., 59., 59., 59.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 87., 87., 87.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 10., 10.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 20.]])
```

In this way we are storing in each column exactly the elements to average, however using `np.mean` would yield the wrong result since the denominator would be `P.shape[0]`, i.e. counting also the zero-ed elements. As a workaround we can sum along the axis and divide by the total count of non-zero elements using `np.count_nonzero`:

```
np.sum(P, axis=0)/np.count_nonzero(P, axis=0)
array([62.5, 65., 71.25, 68.8, 71.83333333, 63., 57.625])
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, but I am not getting the desired result. I was looking for means of P based on t intervals. Also, the len for the mean slices would change, for t>=2 and t<=3, I will have two P elements where for t>=2 and t<=4, I will have 3.

Comment: My desired output for this specific problem is this (62.5, 65.0, 71.25, 68.8, 71.83333333333333, 63.0, 57.625)

Comment: @Hrihaan forgot to change T into P, I edited my answer, check it now please.

Comment: I changed the condition to (T>=2, T<=t_inc) where t_inc goes from 3 to 9 and got this output: [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.] I am not sure though.

Comment: I am setting to zero elements of T below 2 or above T. Setting this condition (T>=2, T<=t_inc) will result in having all zeros.

Comment: Would you please check at your end: my t is [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.] and P is [30. 69. 56. 70. 90. 59. 87. 10. 20.] and the desired output would be (62.5, 65.0, 71.25, 68.8, 71.83333333333333, 63.0, 57.625).

Comment: I just tried what you said but got this output: [13.88888889 21.66666667 31.66666667 38.22222222 47.88888889 49.
 51.22222222]

Comment: @Hrihaan fixed the problem.

Comment: It fixed the problem, would you please explain these two steps: P[np.logical_or(2>T, T>t_inc)]=0 and np.sum(P, axis=0)/np.count_nonzero(P, axis=0).

Comment: I am adding that to the answer, so that it does not get lost in comments for others